# Spark Windows wont start

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying to start ab Spark but I got following error message

```
is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

**Java/ Scala is installed**
[image: Java/ Scala is installed]

**Also I set following user variables and system Path**
[image]

But I get this error when running `sparkR`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the path to spark does not allow for spaces, so i just moved it to `c:\spark`, works fine now